# I can't deploy my Next Js App in vercel, I get an error of Command "npm run build" exited with 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

so I'm following JavaScript Mastery's tutorial regarding next js (shout out to you sir), and I'm trying to deploy it to in `Vercel`, but I can't deploy it and I'm having a difficult time testing out different tutorial. This is the error I got.

```
[13:51:57.286] 15:20  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.287] 16:7  Error: Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 6.  react/jsx-indent
[13:51:57.287] 17:11  Error: Expected indentation of 8 space characters but found 10.  react/jsx-indent
[13:51:57.287] 17:26  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.287] 18:27  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.288] 22:43  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.288] 22:63  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.288] 23:31  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.288] 28:11  Error: Expected indentation of 8 space characters but found 10.  react/jsx-indent
[13:51:57.288] 28:26  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.289] 29:28  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.289] 30:28  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.289] 31:29  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.289] 32:28  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.289] 35:30  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.289] 37:23  Error: Trailing spaces not allowed.  no-trailing-spaces
[13:51:57.289] 41:31  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.289] 
[13:51:57.289] ./components/InsightCard.jsx
[13:51:57.291] 40:28  Error: Newline required at end of file but not found.  eol-last
[13:51:57.291] 
[13:51:57.291] ./components/Navbar.jsx
[13:51:57.291] 3:8  Error: A space is required after '{'.  object-curly-spacing
[13:51:57.291] 3:15  Error: A space is required before '}'.  object-curly-spacing
[13:51:57.291] 3:37  Error: Missing semicolon.  semi
[13:51:57.292] 4:31  Error: Missing semicolon.  semi
[13:51:57.292] 5:8  Error: A space is required after '{'.  object-curly-spacing
[13:51:57.292] 5:20  Error: A space is required before '}'.  object-curly-spacing
[13:51:57.292] 5:44  Error: Missing semicolon.  semi
[13:51:57.292] 14:5  Error: Empty components are self-closing  react/self-closing-comp
[13:51:57.292] 18:13  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.292] 19:19  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.292] 21:21  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.292] 24:11  Error: Trailing spaces not allowed.  no-trailing-spaces
[13:51:57.292] 27:19  Error: Unexpected usage of singlequote.  jsx-quotes
[13:51:57.292] 
[13:51:57.292] ./components/NewFeatures.jsx
[13:51:57.292] 19:28  Error: Newline required at end of file but not found.  eol-last
[13:51:57.292] 
[13:51:57.292] ./components/StartSteps.jsx
[13:51:57.292] 1:20  Error: Strings must use singlequote.  quotes
[13:51:57.292] 3:21  Error: A space is required after '{'.  object-curly-spacing
[13:51:57.293] 3:34  Error: A space is required before '}'.  object-curly-spacing
[13:51:57.293] 5:91  Error: Trailing spaces not allowed.  no-trailing-spaces
[13:51:57.293] 
[13:51:57.293] ./components/index.js
[13:51:57.293] 7:1  Error: Dependency cycle detected.  import/no-cycle
[13:51:57.293] 
[13:51:57.293] info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
[13:51:57.326] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
[13:51:57.641] BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I tried editing the `package.json` but I still get an error. as well as the `next.config.js`

package.json

```
{
  "name": "metaverse13",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.3",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.7",
    "next": "13.0.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
}
```

Comment: It is a linting error. The error itself explains what's wrong. You can eighter fix it and disable lint and deploy. But I would suggest you Fix those So you could Learn some best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the right solution but it works, so what I did here is change

`.eslintrc.json`

```
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "eol-last": "off"
  }
}
```

And update all `.jsx` files and add this line at the end of code

`// Newline character at the end of the file`

So for example the `StartSetups.jsx`

```
import styles from '../styles';

const StartSteps = ({ number, text }) => (
  <div className={`${styles.flexCenter} flex-row`}>
    <div
      className={`${styles.flexCenter} w-[70px] h-[70px] rounded-[24px] bg-[#323F5D]`}
    >
      <p className="font-bold text-[20px] text-white">
        {number}
      </p>
    </div>
    <p className="flex-1 ml-[30px] font-normal text-[18px] text-[#B0B0B0] leading-[32.4px]">
      {text}
    </p>
  </div>
);

export default StartSteps;

// Newline character at the end of the file
```

I did this to all component that has an error.

Please, if you have a better suggestion I'll try it, It seems like what I did is a bad approach but it works, Thank you guys! I'm hoping for a better solution

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. I am also watching JS mastery and I am recieving the same error while deploying to vercel. This part of your solution ( "rules": {
    "eol-last": "off"
  }) helped me remove those red errors on my strings in vs code but I don't understand what you mean when you say we should add "Newline character at the end of the file". Please explain to me thank you

Answer (score 0):

First check the official documentation of the latest Next version and disable the eslint using the given command, then go through every page and change the indentation, braces and quotes one by one. for imports use singleQuotes and for strings use doubleQuotes.

Comment: Until you get the privilege to comment to questions please provide sources for the answer.

Comment: I haven't used any source for the answer, that's how i solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In my case it was my vs code auto-formatting tool Prettier that was causing the problem. You see in my NextJs app every time I saved a file it would automatically make my strings double, which would cause the error but I found out that all I had to do was create a new .prettierrc.json file in my NextJs app. Then inside you should put this:

**.prettierrc.json:**

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  // other Prettier options
}
```

then try saving your files again then you will see prettier format the strings into single quote and then the error goes away. I hope this helps anyone